# Name file with timestamp

Tags: python

I have some code which writes names in the Attendance file (when this person appears in the frame of the camera). And I want to write asomecode, that will create new Attendance file everytime I start my program and someone's face will be in the frame and opencv will recognize him/her).

The file should be named `Attendance_{timestamp}.csv}`.

How do I name a file with a timestamp calculated when the program starts?

I'm going to paste whole code, just to make it clear for you.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
from datetime import datetime

path = 'Training_images'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)
for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNames)


def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)[0]
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList


def markAttendance(name):
    with open('Attendance.csv', 'r+') as f:


        myDataList = f.readlines()
        nameList = []
        for line in myDataList:
            entry = line.split(',')
            nameList.append(entry[0])
        if name not in nameList:
            now = datetime.now()
            dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            f.writelines(f'\n{name},{dtString},{date}')

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print('Encoding Complete')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, -1)
# img = captureScreen()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), None, 0.25, 0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS, facesCurFrame)

    for encodeFace, faceLoc in zip(encodesCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown, encodeFace)
# print(faceDis)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
# print(name)
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = faceLoc
            y1, x2, y2, x1 = y1 * 4, x2 * 4, y2 * 4, x1 * 4
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y2 - 35), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
            cv2.putText(img, name, (x1 + 6, y2 - 6), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            markAttendance(name)


    cv2.imshow('Webcam', img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: do you want to rename a file, or do you want to calculate the file name before creating the file? -- I've removed the opencv tag and adjusted the title because there's absolutely no evidence that OpenCV contributes to your question. afaics, it's a plain python question, basic programming.

Comment: when you open what again?  the attendance file?  How should the attendance files be named?  (why isn't the answer: 'replace 'Attendance' with 'Attendance_some_date'?)  I guess the face/frame refers to some condition you're detecting with opencv (which isn't relevant to this question).  It would help to specify exactly what you want to do (rename the file every time with the timestamp of the last opening?  Or create a new file?).  Regardless, you may wish to look at `datetime`, particularly `datetime.datetime.now()` and the `.strftime` or `.isotime` methods of the resulting object.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz hello. Yes, I want to calculate the file name before creating the file.

Comment: @2e0byo I meant that, I have a code that is writing names in the Attendance file (when this person appear in the frame of the camera). And I want to write a code, that will create new Attendance file everytime I start my program and someone's face will be in the frame and opencv will recognize him/her).

Comment: @MaximLean right, so the date is *the time the program starts running*.  That needs to be *in the question*.  In that case this is a very simple question: 'how do I get the timestamp when I start a program'.  There are any number of answers, but datetime.datetime.now().strftime is probably the easiest.  If you edit the question to include this, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @2e0byo should I change it in other way or it's okay?

Comment: My edit to this question proposes what I think the question actually is.  I'm going to go ahead and answer under this assumption, but feel free to roll back the edit or edit further if you are in fact asking something else.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Since the timestamp depends on when the program starts up, we need to calculate it then and then use it later.  We can get the timestamp in a number of ways, but the easiest is probably:

```py
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M")
attendance_fn = f"Attendance_{timestamp}.csv"
...

with open(attendance_fn, "a+") as f:
...
```

Incidentally there are a few other improvements possible in your csv function: there is no need to use `f.readlines()`: just iterate `f` directly (f is iterable linewise, and you only use the result once so there is no need to waste ram + cycles building a list, only to iterate that list).  You may want (=probably should) to use the inbuilt `csv` module to handle reading/writing for you; and since the file is new for every run of the program there is no reason to hash the disk every time just to find out if a user is in the file.  Instead, keep your list of users in *ram*, and only call the csv writing fn if you need to:

```py
people_seen = set() # at the beginning of the program
...
if name not in people_seen: # where you get the name
    people_seen.add(name)
    markAttendance(name)
```

Disk usage is much slower than querying in ram, and you are unlikely to see so many people you run out of ram.

Comment: I've got a problem:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Attendance_2021-12-22-12-38.csv'
Like, I have something in my mind and I know how to fix it, but I just can't.
Can you help me, please?

Comment: well yes, you need to open the file 'w' if it doesn't exist in order to create it.  But I think iirc you're just appending, so use 'a' ('+' if you want to read it)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Actually I made that, but I forgot to write you.
But, unfortunately, I got another trouble: now, when face is in the frame, it's writing every second in the attendance file. Is there any option, to make it write only one line? And would be perfect, if, for example, face appear in the frame, one line is writing information about it, and when it fade away and comes again, it will write again infomation about this person. I hope you understood me. If you can't help with this, anyway, thank you so much! You helped me out.

Comment: @MaximLean that's really a different question, but have a look at the second part of my answer: you need to keep track of who you have seen, and only append to the file if the name isn't in `people_seen()`.  However that really is a separate question.

Comment: should I create new question or?

Comment: You should probably have a go at implementing it.  Checking a local var (a set is best, but a list would do) for the name before doing anything, and only processing + adding the name to the var if not present is about as basic as it gets.  But if you can't get it working, a *simple, minimal* example would make a decent question  guess.

Comment: Everything is working and I have last **but**.
Code is writing names in one line, as it should, but when it's second appearence in the frame - nothing happens, how it was 1 line - it's still 1 line.
I'm just thinking what can I do with it (make that it will write second, third, etc appearence in the file).

Comment: Maybe make loop inside a `for` loop?